# Create Table in vertica through RJDBC

Tags: r, vertica, rjdbc

I saw a similar question in Stackoverflow, but it was not answered. Please let me know if this question is already answered elsewhere. Sorry for the noise. If not, here is my question.

I'm connected to Vertica from R through RJDBC. I have no problem in querying and getting results like `select * <tablename>`. But I tried to create a table using the command

```
dbSendQuery(vertica, "create table schema.tablename(
   ID      INTEGER,
   PRODUCT VARCHAR(100))
   ORDER BY ID
   UNSEGMENTED ALL NODES;")
```

I get this error

> Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
>   for ",  :    Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for create table
>   schema.tablename(
>                        ID                INTEGER,
>                        PRODUCT        VARCHAR(100)
>                        ORDER BY ID
>                        UNSEGMENTED ALL NODES; ([Vertica]JDBC A ResultSet was expected but not generated from query "create table
>   schema.tablename(

I wonder, how I should create a table in vertica through R using RJDBC.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to try `dbSendUpdate()` instead, no?

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, now I'm trying to connect Oracle from R. I followed the steps from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407116/connecting-oracle-from-r) but still I get `Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found.`

Comment: If you have a different question, post it as a different question.

Comment: Hi, now I'm trying to connect Oracle from R. I followed the steps from link. My driver connection oDriver = JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="/path/ojdbc7.jar") but still I get Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found. I have ORACLE_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH setup. I'm not sure what else I'm missing